# Connected to database but not receiving any data when sails.query is executed

Tags: sql-server, sails.js

<del>The connection to mssql server is established</del> but when i try to execute the .query() method , i am not able to get any result.The page keeps on loading and doesn't get any response from database.

The following is my connection.js:

```
sql_server_main:{
    adapter:'sails-mssqlserver',
    host:'***********',
    port:3180,
    user:'soa_user',
    password:'******',
    database:'SSISDB'
  }
```

SoaController.js is as following:-

```
    module.exports = {

    view_all:function(req,res){
        sails.log('inside view_all');
        Soa.query('exec job_batch',function(err,result){
            if(err){
                  return res.serverError(err);
            }
            sails.log('query_execute');
            return res.json(result);
        })
    }
};
```

When i execute the query in sql server it works.

I don't know if the problem is with the database server or with sails.

Comment: You should use SQL Server Profiler in order to see what your application is sending to server. If you see that it **sends** your query correctly you should investigate further, once you know the spid of your query, filter sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks by this spid and find for what it's waiting for and update your question with this waiting

Comment: I'm sorry for providing misinformation. When i used sql server profiler, i realized sails is not getting connected to the database.

Comment: I think the problem is that i am behind restrictive proxy which is not letting sql server to send the data. Is there a way to get past that in sails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all i had to do was add

```
options:{encrypt:true}
```

in connection.js